# How to build webkit on Linux

Tags: webkit

I am arch user and occurs a strange problem during the building webkit.

I get the source code from the official site (http://nightly.webkit.org/builds/trunk/src/1) and follow its steps to the building source code. (http://www.webkit.org/building/build.html)

Obviously, I have not built the source code. Hence, the output message is crazy ! I have no idea to solve this. Please help me.  Thanks.

```
[gapry@arch410 WebKit-r167533]$ ./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --clean
[gapry@arch410 WebKit-r167533]$ ./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug

====================================================================
 WebKit is now built (00m:00s). 
====================================================================
[gapry@arch410 WebKit-r167533]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose WebKit port; try for instance:

```
./Tools/Scripts/build-webkit --debug --gtk
```